# Having trouble with ItemContainerStyle on a Treeview 

Tags: wpf, treeview, itemcontainerstyle

I have the following XML being set on my treeview:

```
<Root Value="YES">
 <Child Name="Test">
 <Sibling Data="Yes">
  <Last UserData="1"/>
 </Sibling>
 <Sibling Data="No"/>
 </Child>
 <Child Name="Test2"/>
</Root>
```

and then I have set the following code in my window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="dataProvider" XPath="Root" Source="C:\XML.xml" />

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Root" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Value}" />

      <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate>
                <Border Background="Blue">
                  <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Child" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Sibling" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Data}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <TreeView Margin="12" x:Name="trv"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataProvider}}" />
  </Grid>
```

I would like to have a border control wrap around all the subitems for every node as in this image:

http://www.hardcodet.net/uploads/2008/03/tree-dialogik.png

In other words, you'll notice in the image I've linked to, the parent node **dialogik.Memory** has a dark gray border that goes around it and around its children. That's the effect I want to achieve.

What do I need to change in my code to have it work correctly ???

Thanks !!

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142510/hierarchicaldatatemplate-not-working - it has a bit of an example of using expanders.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with the TreeView.  You could use an Expander though, see here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx

..and then bind it similarly: you'd have an ItemsControl that outputs an Expander for each item, and the Expander would then contain another ItemsControl for child items, recursively.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I really hope you get this comment 3 years later. I have the exact same problem as OP but I do not know how to implement your suggestion. I need to put a border round all of the children for certain nodes. Can you alter your answer to demonstrate that?