# HierarchicalDataTemplate not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am trying to use a HierarchicalDataTemplate to recursively create expanders with items in them but when I use the HierarchicalDataTemplate I only get the first level of items displayed.

Please let me know if you need anyore information.

Heres the what the xaml would look like if I was writing by hand:

```
<GroupBox Header="SectionHeader">
    <StackPanel >
        <Expander VerticalAlignment="Top" Header="SubSectionHeader">
            <StackPanel>
                <Expander VerticalAlignment="Top" Header="SubSectionHeader" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <StackPanel>
                        etc......
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander>
         </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Heres what I have so far.

Xaml:

```
<ItemsControl Name="lstMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GroupBox Header="{Binding Section.SectionName}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SubSections}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BinderTemplate}" />
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="BinderTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubSections}" DataType="{x:Type local:SubSectionViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Expander Header="{Binding SubSection.SubSectionName}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Data Classes:

```
class TopViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<SectionViewModel> _sections = new ObservableCollection<SectionViewModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<SectionViewModel> Sections
    {
        get
        {
            return _sections;
        }
        set
        {
            _sections = value;
        }
    }
}

public class SectionViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<MaterialViewModel> _materials = new ObservableCollection<MaterialViewModel>();
    ObservableCollection<SubSectionViewModel> _subSections = new ObservableCollection<SubSectionViewModel>();
    Section _section;

    public Section Section
    {
        get
        {
            return _section;
        }
        set
        {
            _section = value;
        }
    }

    public string MaterialName
    {
        get { return Section.SectionName; }
        set { Section.SectionName = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MaterialViewModel> Materials
    {
        get
        {
            return _materials;
        }
        set
        {
            _materials = value;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SubSectionViewModel> SubSections
    {
        get
        {
            return _subSections;
        }
        set
        {
            _subSections = value;
        }
    }
}

public class SubSectionViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<MaterialViewModel> _materials = new ObservableCollection<MaterialViewModel>();
    ObservableCollection<SubSectionViewModel> _subSections = new ObservableCollection<SubSectionViewModel>();
    SubSection _subSection;

    public ObservableCollection<MaterialViewModel> Materials
    {
        get
        {
            return _materials;
        }
        set
        {
            _materials = value;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SubSectionViewModel> SubSections
    {
        get
        {
            return _subSections;
        }
        set
        {
            _subSections = value;
        }
    }

    public SubSection SubSection
    {
        get
        {
            return _subSection;
        }
        set
        {
            _subSection = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a key bit in your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` - how to render the subelements:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="BinderTemplate" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubSections}" 
    DataType="{x:Type local:SubSectionViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Expander Header="{Binding SubSection.SubSectionName}">
            <ItemsControl Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SubSections}" 
                      ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource BinderTemplate}"/>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

EDIT: Not to steal @BDE's thunder, but he/she's mostly correct about the use of `DataType` - but this is the way you'd "simplify" the above XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" 
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
         <!-- normal template for sections -->
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SectionViewModel}">
            <GroupBox Header="{Binding Section.SectionName}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SubSections}"/>
            </GroupBox>
         </DataTemplate>
         <!-- hierarchical template for subsections -->
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
              DataType="{x:Type local:SubSectionViewModel}">
           <StackPanel>
               <Expander Header="{Binding SubSection.SubSectionName}">
                   <ItemsControl Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding SubSections}"/>
               </Expander>
           </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!-- 
           no need to specify ItemTemplate if WPF can suss out all the item types 
         -->
        <ItemsControl Name="lstMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks :) I had tried doing this but tried to use the template as a static resource instead of a dynamic one and got a compile time error :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is to add an `ItemsControl` to the `Expander` in your data template, and bind the `ItemsSource` there.

Also, since you specify the `DataType` in the data template definition, so you don't have to directly set the `ItemTemplate` by key name for your toplevel `ItemsControl`.

If you modifiy you XAML like this it might do what you want:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SubSectionViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Expander Header="{Binding SubSection.SubSectionName}">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SubSections}"/>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl Name="lstMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GroupBox Header="{Binding Section.SectionName}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SubSections}"/>
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: You need the data type on the first DataTemplate as well for the template->type inference to work (see my edit)

Comment: Agreed, if you want all the data templates together in the resources section. In the code that I posted though, since the template for `SectionViewModel` is directly specified in the ItemsControl and not in the resources, it should still work, correct? It looks like it works in my testing at least.

Comment: Huh. Fun..it didn't infer the template type when I threw a quick skeleton together in Blend...

Comment: Weird. Which versions are you using? I was testing this with VS2010, not using Blend.

Comment: Blend 4 - although i suppose it's entirely possible we vary slightly in xaml - I didn't save my little harness, so what I posted in my answer is all that remains. :(

Comment: Oh well, I think the point is that there are a couple of ways to implement something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Section.SectionName shall be MaterialName?

Look Lines :

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SubSections}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BinderTemplate}" />
```

and

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="BinderTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubSections}" DataType="{x:Type local:SubSectionViewModel}">
```

I think, if firs line binding is SubSections, so second line instead of

```
   {Binding Path=SubSections}
```

you probably shall write

```
    {Binding}
```

SubSectionName i do not find in your classes.

Please, add more classes